# Jenkins pipeline more rows in stage view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline and we are running and we have 14 different concurrent runs running at once. (waiting for a set period of time).

Only 12 rows are showing on the stage view. Is there a way to expand the stage view to see more rows?

Answer (score 7):

It comes a little late, but the answer is: add this parameter to the Jenkins Java VM (e.g. in `/etc/default/jenkins`):

```
-Dcom.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob=32
```

So for instance

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob=32"
```

(`32` is the number of rows displayed after restarting Jenkins).

Comment: Is this applicable only for `Cloudbees Jenkins` ?

Comment: No. You can use it for the community edition too.

Answer (score 4):

@Stefan Seidel 's anwser works great, but our Jenkins instance is runing in a docker container, so it's hard to access the Jenkins' config file.

After some research, I found a way to do it in the Jenkins dashboard website (no need to restart Jenkins):

1. Open "Manage Jenkins" -> "Script Console"
2. Run the script:

```java
System.setProperty('com.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob', '32')
```

Comment: Does this survive a restart/reboot?

Answer (score -4):

Are you using any custom plugins, or outdated plugins? For me it's controlled by browser view size, and when that's not large enough, the panel with the stages is scrollable. See the following images:

Highly scrolled out browser:

[image: All the stages]

Too small view's default:

[image: Too small to fit everything]

After scrolling right on the panel with the stages in the small browser view:

[image]

Comment: you confused rows with columns...  I need more rows (up and down)... the number of builds showing.  not the number of columns.