# Can I let Jenkins stage view result rows show more than 10

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

- My Jenkins Version: 2.303.1
- Stage View show 10 rows(build results) now.

[Jenkins Stage View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEYC.jpg)

Comment: our actual question is not easy to understand. Here is a guideline for you on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins pipeline more rows in stage view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076957/jenkins-pipeline-more-rows-in-stage-view)

Comment: Adding more rows at the start could be slow. Maybe is time to add  pagination and filters :). More than 25 likes and I might try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the discarding limit according to Melkjot will only increase the number of runs that are stored, it doesn't change the number ob entries shown in the stage view. However, there is a hardwired parameter mentioned in the plugins documentation at https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view/

com.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob (default: 10)

Answer (score -1):

Open job configuration, under **General** tab check **Discard old builds**. Enter the number of builds you want to keep into **Max # of builds to keep** field.